# Check if N and its double exists

Tags: java

What's the problem with my code? when I debugged the control is not going to the return statement to return true.

Sample input:
[10,2,5,3]

The output should be true since 10=5*2 but I am getting false

```
class Solution {
public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
    //[10,2,5,3]
    
    int i=arr.length-1;
    
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length-2;j++)
    {
       if (arr[i] == 2 * arr[j] || arr[j] == 2 * arr[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you print out all possible values of `i` and `j`, then you get

```
2, 0
1, 1
```

Therefore not all values are being checked hence it never returning.

---

If you are trying to find out whether any number in the array is double the other, then I would implement something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

        if(arr[i] == 2 * arr[j] || arr[j] == 2 * arr[i]) {

            return true;
        }
    }
}

return false;
```